# Rephrasing typescript signature correctly, returning custom type rather than strict signature required for a method

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript I have a simple class

```
class Point {
  x;
  y;
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Besides I have written a Painter literal like this

```
let Painter = {
  ramdomPoint: ():[number, number] => {
```

which returns an array of two numbers that later on I will use in something like

```
ctx.moveTo.apply(ctx, Painter.ramdomPoint());
```

for a HTML5 canvas piece. Remember that moveTo officially requires two numbers for the x and y coordinates in a html5 canvas next animation frame.

My question is that for `ramdomPoint` I want to express that I want a`Point` in the Array, in my mind something like

```
ramdomPoint: ():[Point]
```

rather than

```
ramdomPoint: ():[number, number]
```

please note that actually `point` is already a `number, number`

is this possible altogether?

Comment: Why not a `type Point = [number, number]` and then `randomPoint():Point`

Comment: many thanks faizuddin! 

it seems to work the way you propose but I then lose the possibility of including the class. It seems to accept only either the class or the type statement

Comment: Yes, there can't be two things with the same name.

Comment: https://www.sitepen.com/blog/advanced-typescript-concepts-classes-and-types/

Comment: yeah. the key here is that there are many advantages of having a constructor in a class rather than a type statement

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the help!

I finally managed to achieve what I wanted via a function.

My final code looks like this

```
type Point = [number, number];
function Point(x: number, y: number):Point {
  return [x, y]
}

let Painter = {
  ramdomPoint: (): Point => {
    return Point(Math.random() * w, Math.random() * h);
  }
};
```

I think that, like this, it is expressive enough. I hope this helps others! Greetings from Spain :)